# elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{bmatrix} -5 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Why is this not the elemtary matrix? 
Why do we not change the first row of the second row place and thus be elementary matrix?

Comment: That would be one operation and it still would not be $I$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, "An elementary matrix is a matrix which differs from the identity matrix by **one** single elementary row operation."
You need at least two elementary operations to obtain the matrix from the identity.